# Using a custom user model with .NET 8 Identity API Endpoints

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using the new Identity API endpoints from my ASP.NET Core API project, but I would like to use more custom properties for application user.

My user class looks like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string? Surname { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Years and fraction of year of experience on drums
    /// </summary>
    public float Experience { get; set; }
}
```

Identity configuration:

```
public static IServiceCollection ConfigureIdentity(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var connectionString= configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityConnection");
    //Guard.Against.Null(connectionString, $"Connection string for 'IdentityConnection' not found");

    services.AddDbContext<AppIdentityDbContext>((sp, options) =>
    {
        options.UseSqlite("DataSource=app.db");
    });

    services.AddScoped<IApplicationDbContext>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<AppIdentityDbContext>());

    services.AddScoped<AppIdentityDbContextInitializer>();

    services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<ApplicationUser>()
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>();

    services.AddAuthorizationBuilder();
    services.AddTransient<IIdentityService, IdentityService>();

    services.AddAuthorizationBuilder()
        .AddPolicy(Policies.CanAddHomework, policy => policy.RequireRole(Roles.Teacher));

    return services;
}
```

And in API Program class: `app.MapIdentityApi<ApplicationUser>();`

Database has been created with custom properties, but while using the register endpoint, I am only able to pass only email and password, no matter what I've sent in the request body. I can't even set the username which is the default property in the IdentityUser class. Always the username is email.

Is there an option to configure the register endpoint to accept a custom body or do I need to get rid of the Identity API endpoints and implement authentication with the old Identity?

Comment: You could try use get a database from old model. Modify your database manually in Db editor designer, then use db-first approach to get the new Context and models.

Comment: I believe you have to dump the default API endpoint stuff and use the old-school way.

Answer (score 1):

Default implementation which added by app.MapIdentityApi() cannot be overridden. You have to create a separate endpoint manually and use it for user registration.